# Balancing Deep-Fried Tarantula Spider with chili sauce

Tags: chili-peppers

[Deep-Fried Tarantula Spider](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/deep-fried-tarantula-spider-51184810), is not as disgusting as it first sounds, in fact they have become quite a culinary sensation.  I have been thinking about a chili dip, but I do not want the chili to over-power the spider, what type of chili pepper should I use in my chili-sauce?

Comment: Doug, no food pairing questions please, at least not on the main site. You could discuss the topic over in chat, of course, but I'm not sure how many users are online at this moment

Comment: The humour in making a kind of outlandish question stand rejected on such a banal reason ... admit it, it is tempting :)

Comment: If I should not ask about pairing, why is there a pairing tag?

Comment: Because the tag description reads: "Food pairing questions, but only very specific ones. Do not use for "what goes with X?" (off-topic)." Find more at the [info page for "pairing"](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/pairing/info).

Comment: I have changed the question, taken off the pairing tag as well, so hope that helps.

Comment: Just been edited by @Jefromi, again, basically changing what I asked to what he wants to be asked.

Comment: This isn't really a pairing question anymore, though I'm afraid it may not be a very interesting question; you can avoid overpowering it with any kind of chile as long as you use an appropriate quantity.

Comment: I changed your title from the original general one to match the body of the question, which I can only assume is what *you* want to ask. If you don't think it's a good summary, I apologize, and by all means edit it more. But please don't leave your title asking the off topic pairing question - that's part of why four users have already voted to close.

Comment: If the criteria for being put on hold are as above then I am surprised any questions get through.

Comment: Well, my edit was all about trying to help you avoid closure for the reasons Stephie pointed out, but it seems the community doesn't think it was enough to avoid all issues. (And we have *plenty* of questions that don't get closed - it's just that they're more in the vein of "how do I do X?" than "what should I eat?")

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you like the flavor of. Chiles don't vary strongly enough in flavor (as opposed to heat) to really have to worry about some overwhelming it and some not, so you really can just use what you like. If you don't want it too overpowering, use a small enough quantity that it isn't - make a sauce, not a pure chile paste.

If you mean specifically keeping the heat under control, be sure to thoroughly remove the seeds and membrane, and if you're especially sensitive to heat, start with a not too hot pepper.

(The question of what goes best with it is really down to personal preference, so I won't attempt to answer in that regard - it'd be off-topic anyway.)